# How does one set a custom WebAppClassLoader in Jetty through config?

Tags: java, jetty, classloader, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to configure a Jetty (6.x) WebAppContext with a custom subclass of [WebAppClassLoader](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader.html).  In code (Scala), it's simply this:

```
  val context = new WebAppContext()
  val cwacl = new CustomWebAppClassLoader(context)
  context.setClassLoader(cwacl)
  ...
```

This works fine when embedding Jetty.  In production, however, I just deploy a war file to a stand-alone jetty instance, so there's no opportunity to configure things in code like this.

I can't figure out how to do the same thing via Jetty's configuration files.  Any help is appreciated.

Bonus: How would you configure [maven-jetty-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) to use the CustomWebAppClassLoader :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the context config files. There are examples in the `contexts/` directory.

This would be something along these lines:

```
<Configure id="mycontext1" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="classLoader">
        <New class="f.q.n.CustomWebAppClassLoader">
           <Arg><Ref id="mycontext1"/></Arg></New>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

(See the [Jetty XML Syntax configuration reference](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Syntax+Reference) for more details.)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a context config file, you can set the classloader attributes in the pom.xml file, for jetty >= 8.x e.g. not scanning any class within WEB-INF for faster startup:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <webApp>
        <webInfIncludeJarPattern>^$</webInfIncludeJarPattern>
      </webApp>
      <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
      <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Reference: [Jetty plugin webapp configuration](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp)